# i want to convert string to json string and send it via ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have this function

```
var array = $("#achievement").val().split(',');
var string = JSON.stringify(array);
var data = '{"action":"add_user_achievements","data":{"gameid":"'+$("#game_id").val()+'","achievements":"'+string+'"}}';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myhost+'games',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if (data.Success == true){
            sweetAlert("Success!", data.Message);
        } else {
            sweetAlert("Oops!", data.Message);
        }
    },
    error: function(a, b, c){ 
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
    }
});
```

But it gives me 500 internal server error. On the other, I am using node js and this is my function.

```
function addUserAchievements(req,callback){

  global.users.find({"uname":req.body.data.uname},
    function(err,doc){
      console.log('err:'+err+' and doc:'+doc);
      if((doc=='')){
        callback(false,err,"No user with such id exists");
      }else{

        var data = JSON.parse(req.body.data.achievements);
        global.users.update( {"uname" : req.body.data.uname,
          "games.gameid":req.body.data.gameid},
          {
            $addToSet:{"games.$.achievements":{$each:data}}
          },function(err,doc){
            if(err){
              callback(false,err,"achievments are not added",null);
            }else{
              callback(true,err,"Achievements are added",null);
            }
          });
      }
  });
}
```

How can I successfully post my data over there? I don't want to mess with server so what should I do?

Comment: `500` error means there is error on server can you please add details of error?

Comment: a) Why would you build JSON manually? That's bound to fail. b) Why would put JSON inside JSON and then convert a string containing JSON to JSON again? You end up with JSON inside JSON inside JSON. You are not escaping the quotation marks contained in `string`, so `data` is most likely not valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating string not JSON Object since it contains '' at first and last position so your api is treating your request data as string and giving error.

try this

```
var array = $("#achievement").val().split(',');

var requestBodyObj = {
    "action": "add_user_achievements",
    "data": {
        "gameid": $("#game_id").val(),
        "achievements": array
    }
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myhost+'games',
    data: requestBodyObj,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if (data.Success == true){
            sweetAlert("Success!", data.Message);
        } else {
            sweetAlert("Oops!", data.Message);
        }
    },
    error: function(a, b, c){ 
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
    }
});
```

Comment: *"You are creating string not JSON Object "* JSON can only consist inside of string in JavaScript. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Also, why do `var string = JSON.stringify(array);`?

Comment: the `string` part will fail...will still be stringifying that string which is pointless

Answer (score 2):

You are manually creating a json string so there is no need to stringify it.
Manually creating json is also a terrible practice and can be prone to code errors. There is rarely ever any good reason to manually create it when most languages have serialize methods

Also when you send as json you need to set `contentType` if you are expecting to receive it as application/json in the request body

Using object to create data structure then stringify the object

```
var array = $("#achievement").val().split(',');

var data = {
    "action":"add_user_achievements",
    "data":{"gameid":$("#game_id").val(),
            "achievements":array
     }
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myhost+'games',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType:'application/json',
    success....

})
```

As for the 500 error you need to inspect the server side error to get more specifics

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server code is correct you have listed 500 error which comes from your NodeJs code. Please resolve it first then use below code to correct your Ajax request.

> Do not make it to much complicated just create a data object and append rest of your data into that object and pass into Ajax-call.

```
var data =  {};
    data.action = add_user_achievements;
    data.gameid = $("#game_id").val();
    data.achievements = $("#achievement").val().split(',');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myhost+'games',
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if (data.Success == true){
            sweetAlert("Success!", data.Message);
        } else {
            sweetAlert("Oops!", data.Message);
        }
    },
    error: function(a, b, c){ 
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
    }
});
```

Hope this will Help thanks :)

Answer (score -2):

you probably need to get an object to send

```
...
url: myhost+"games",
data: JSON.parse(data),
dataType: "json",
...
```